# Without A and B / without A or B / Without A nor B

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning, or-nor

1. Solutions without overcomplications and mistakes.
2. Solutions without overcomplications or mistakes.
3. Solutions without overcomplitations nor mistakes.

Nominal Sentences of my own. Does one not make sense in english?
If so why?
What is the meaning attached to each grammatically sound nominal sentence?
Constructions: without A and B / without A or B / without A nor B
Which is/are impossible/incorrect?
For the correct one(s), what is the logical implication?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> **Solutions with neither overcomplications nor mistakes.**

We often pair "neither" with "nor".

1 and 2 could be ambiguous.  To avoid it, do not use the parallel construction.  Instead say

> Solutions without overcomplications and without mistakes